# DatePicker - with link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

here is what i wrote in my HTMLHelper Class:

```
html.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(function() { $('#" + name + "').datepicker({ onSelect: openday,dateFormat: 'yymmdd' }); });");

html.Append("function openday(dateText, inst) { window.location = '" + link + "/' + encodeURIComponent(dateText); }</script>");
```

here is the call from the view:

`<%Html.DatePicker("Date",Url.Action("Dropped","ProcessList"),this.ViewData["TheDate"]) %>`

so.. when i click at the datepicker the first time.. everything works..
but the problem is the second click: i get the follwing url: ProcessList/Dropped/20110416/20110401

What can i do?
Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript you provided seems to be correct; I created a simple test here: http://jsfiddle.net/2CrSh/. You may want to look at the `link` variable.

I suspect that you didn't post the code that contains the bug....